# ifstream binary file wrong

Tags: c++, file

I have to read a binary file that is structured like that :
1 byte for n, n bytes, 4 bytes, etc

That's my code :

```
char length;
file >> length;

char c[ 64 ];
file.read( c, length );

c[ length ] = 0;

int ver;
file >> ver;
```

The problem : ver is always 0 ( on ~2500 files ) while it should not be. length ouput the correct value, c too. And after calling read, tellg returns -1.

Comment: Do you have the code that creates the input file? If the file is really a binary file, shouldn't you be using `file.read(&length, 1);` and `file.read(&ver, sizeof(int));`?

Comment: I use std::ifstream file( path, std::ios::binary ) to create the file. So i tried your solution, it worked. But I don't understand, >> operator can't be used instead of read? And I had to cast &ver to char* to get this working, why?

Comment: And what's the code that writes the data to the file?

Comment: I have no idea. The file is generated by an external tool.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You said

> 1 byte for n, n bytes, 4 bytes, etc

I would suggest using:

```
char length;
file.read(&length, 1);

// Check the value of length and make sure you have enough space.
if ( length > 63 )
{
   // Deal with error condition
}

char c[ 64 ];
file.read( c, length );

c[ length ] = 0;

// Use a type that is know to be 4 bytes wide.
// Use read() instead of formatted input.
int32_t ver;
file.read(reinterpret_cast<char*>(&ver), sizeof(ver));
```

Comment: Is there a way to avoid cast of &ver? Getting error if I don't.

Comment: Unfortunately, there isn't.